# jQuery show(), hide(), and the :visible selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function showHide(showWhat) {
    if (showWhat == 'a') {
        $('.group-a').show();
        $('.group-b, .group-c').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').show();
        $('.group-b, .group-c').not(':has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').hide();
    } else if (showWhat == 'b') {
        $('.group-b').show();
        $('.group-a, .group-c').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').show();
        $('.group-a, .group-c').not(':has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').hide();
    } else if (showWhat == 'c') {
        $('.group-c').show();
        $('.group-a, .group-b').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').show();
        $('.group-a, .group-b').not(':has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').hide();
    } else if (showWhat == 'all') {
        $('.group-a, .group-b, .group-c').show();
    }
    $('.none').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(element).parent().children(':visible').length > 1) {
            $(element).hide();
        } else {
            $(element).show();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(showHide('all'));
</script>

Show:<br/>
<button onclick="showHide('a');">Group A</button><br/>
<button onclick="showHide('b');">Group B</button><br/>
<button onclick="showHide('c');">Group C</button><br/>
<button onclick="showHide('all');">All</button>

<ul>
    <li class="none">none found</li>
    <li class="group-a">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>A: foo</label>
    </li>
    <li class="group-a">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>A: bar</label>
    </li>
    <li class="group-b">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>B: foo</label>
    </li>
    <li class="group-b">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>B: bar</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wnay9a8/3/

I have a list which contains multiple groups, each group being identified by a shared class. Items in each group each have a checkbox. There is an additional item in the list to indicate no other items were shown.

I have a javascript method which filters the list contents such that items of the specified group are shown, and any items of any of the other groups if they're checked.

If, after applying any filter, there are no items to show, the "none found" item should show. If there is even one item to show, the "none found" item should be hidden.

For most cases, my design works, but for a few cases it shows the "none found" message when items were, in fact, found.

In my JSFiddle, if you check one item, then filter to Group C, then both the checked item and "none found" items are shown.

Is there some sort of race condition or something that causes elements to register as not visible when they actually are (or vice-versa)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kind of a moron. There's no bug or race condition in jQuery going on here.

If I exclude the `<li class="none">none found</li>` element from the selector used to decide whether to show "none found", then everything works as intended.

Instead of:

```
if ($(element).parent().children(':visible').length > 1) {
```

I should have done:

```
if ($(element).parent().children(':visible:not(.none)').length > 0) {
```

This would always exclude the "none found" element, and count from the others in the list to determine if there are any items found.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showHide(showWhat) {
    if (showWhat == "all")
    {
        $(".g").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".g").hide();
        $(".group-" + showWhat).show();
              $('.g').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').show();

    }
    $('.none').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(element).parent().children(':visible').length > 1) {
            $(element).hide();
        } else {
            $(element).show();
        }
    });
```

}

here is a working and much more straight forward fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/0L7j91Lq/

Comment: Your jsfiddle fails to keep checked elements visible.